# Put the result of a PHP request in a JSON array and decode it in AJAX

Tags: php, json, ajax

I want to put the result of a query into an JSON array  and then decode it in an Ajax success function where I will have an array of variables user.id, user.name and user.age.
How can I do that?
Here is my php result

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);      
   $totalUsers = $result->num_rows;
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $counter=0;
        while($row_rs= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $userId = $row_rs['id'];
            $userName= $row_rs['name'];
            $age= $row_rs['age'];

            $counter++;
        }
   }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `echo json_encode($php_array);` ... `var data = JSON.parse(ajax_result);` If you juse jQuery and send the correct Content-Type header (`application/json`), then jQuery parses the JSON for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get your data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$totalUsers = $result->num_rows;
$row_rs= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// Set JSON Headers
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Output result as JSON (Sends status 200)
echo json_encode($row_rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the php code where you need to return $users array for multiple users

```
 <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);      
   $totalUsers = $result->num_rows;
    $users=array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     $counter=0;
     while($row_rs= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $users[$counter]['userId'] = $row_rs['id'];
        $users[$counter]['userName']= $row_rs['name'];
        $users[$counter]['age']= $row_rs['age'];

        $counter++;
     }
   }
   return json_encode(array('data'=>$users,'totalUsers'=>$totalUsers))
  ?>
```

Following is the script for ajax request

```
 $.get('url' , function(data){
       console.log(data);
    // you can access totalUsers like this -: data.totalUsers
     alert(data.totalUsers);
       $.each(data.data, function(key, value)
        {
           alert(JSON.stringify(value);
          // Now you can use value.userID , value.Username , value.age
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I include in the json_encode the $totalUsers variable which is not part of the $users array ?

Comment: I do not get any result in the $.get('url' , function(data){ I have tried with a siple alert (data) and the chrome screen stays empty. When I load the php script, I get the correct result. But not with the js script. Please help.

Comment: You have to specify the Ajax URL for the above specified php file  from which you need to the data $.get('url') won't work specify original URL for Ajax instead of url

Answer (score 0):

**Server-side**:

You need to create an empty `array` before you iterate the results, like this:

```
$myResults = array();
```

Then, inside the iteration you will need to add new elements to the `array`, like this:

```
$myResults[]= array(
    "userId" => $rows_rs["id"], 
    "userName" => $rows_rs["name"], 
    "age" => $rows_rs["age"]
);
```

This is what you need to `echo` from server-side:

```
echo json_encode($myResults);
```

**Client-side**:

```
function callback(response) {
    var myObject = $.parseJSON(response);
    //whatever
}
```

and then use this `callback` as a callback.